# If text match in range conditonal formula Google Sheets error

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, match, textmatching

I'm trying to get a match in a range of text in Google Sheets basically I'm using this formula:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(H2:M2, "Hi"), "Yes", "No")
```

But I'm getting an error that is:

[image]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing an array in a function that is not designed to take arrays as input so you need to enable them.

Try:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(REGEXMATCH(H2:M2, "Hi"), "Yes", "No"))
```

> I'm trying to do this: =IF(("Hi"=H2:L2),"Approve","No qualify") =IF(("Here"= H2:L2),"Approve","No qualify")

Assuming E1:E2 is the list of values to check against A1:C1, you can try:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(countif(E1:E2,A1:C1),"Approved","Not qualified"))
```

[image]